# Cards not aligning properly in card-group

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place these elements so that they align their bottom section. Been trying this while looking at the bootstrap reference, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong that is causing this behaviour.

From what I read on the docs, card-group class should align the bottom of its children, but somehow this isn't the case... Does anyone know why this is not working?

projects.html

```html
<app-search></app-search>
<div class="card-group justify-content-center">
    <div *ngFor="let project of filtered | async" class="card-group justify-content-center">
        <app-project class="m-3" [title]="project.name" [preview]="project.preview" [text]="project.text"></app-project>
    </div>
</div>
```

Project.html (app-project component)

```html
<div class="card" style="max-width: 320px; margin-left: 10px;">
    <h4 class="card-title text-center card-header">{{title}}</h4>
    <img class="card-img-top" [src]="preview" alt="Card image">
    <div class="align-content-center card-margin card-text text-justify">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

project.css

```css
@mixin cardMargin {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

.card-margin {
    @include cardMargin();
}
```

[image: Visual]([![enter image description here]

Comment: you can give fixed height to card-text class so that all the cards should be in the same height. like .card-text { height: 60px }.

Comment: I could, but than its no longer responsive. I would like to keep it as responsive as possible.

Comment: Additionally, I am going to load this text data from JSON, so it might change in the future. if it would become longer I would run into issues.

Comment: No, actually it is responsive only because you are giving the same height to class' card-text'. But if the content is increased then the text gets overflow out of the box. so for that, you can use { max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;

Comment: This could be because of some other custom CSS you have applied. Can you provide a repro in StackBlitz?

Comment: @TorbenVanAssche, in a bootstrap card, is aligned, `card-footer` or `list-group list-group-flush`, read carefully the docs:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#header-and-footer

Comment: @JohnsMathew I'll do you one better. https://github.com/GrimZero/Portfolio It doesnt seem unliky I would forget something making a repro. this is safer xD

Comment: @TorbenVanAssche Please see my answer below

Comment: I have marked your answer as my solution @JohnsMathew. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `div` to loop through the `filtered` array. According to your current code, you have a `card-group` and for each card, you have two enclosing `div`s. The additional classes in these `div`s are causing issues with the default behaviour of bootstrap cards. You can directly use `ngFor` on the `app-project` component, like the below code:

```
<div class="card-group justify-content-center">
    <app-project *ngFor="let project of filtered | async" class="m-3" [project]="project"></app-project>
</div>
```

I removed one of the enclosing `div`s.

Now, you would have a four `app-project` components inside the `card-group` div. If you inspect, you can find that all `app-project` are of the same height. This is the default bootstrap configuration - all elements inside the `card-group` are of equal height. In your case, each card within the `app-project` is aligned to the top. This is why you are seeing empty space below each card. To resolve this, we need to make the `card` equal height as the `app-project` component. We can do that by making the `app-project` component a flex container. Apply the below CSS to `projects.component.scss`:

```
app-project {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Now each card would take the full height of the `app-container`. This would make the top and bottom of each card to be aligned with each other.

Comment: That worked. I had an additional div because I assumed (wrongfully) that the ngFor loop had to be in a structure like you would do in code. I did not know they could be in the same element in the html.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments you can give height to the class `card-text`. check the below CSS snippet code.

```
.card-text {   
   height: 100px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

The above CSS will hide the card-text if it's beyond the 100px height.

you can check the below [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-wkjavd?file=src/app/app.component.scss) here and the below code is responsive with the bootstrap grid.

Comment: This is not a solution, its a workaround. I know its possible to make it decide the height by using the classes bootstrap provides. I just seem to have overlooked some detail that is causing a problem